# using a checkbox in listview item android-xamarin

Tags: android, android-listview, mono

I have an app which has list view with a button below it.in the list view each row has textview and a checkbox and other stuff.
this is my adapter:

```
internal class PizzaAdapter : BaseAdapter
{
    private class MyViewHolder : Java.Lang.Object
    {
        public CheckBox Chb { get; set; }
        public TextView Name { get; set; }
        public TextView Content { get; set; }
        public RadioButton One { get; set; }
        public TextView OneT { get; set; }
        public RadioButton Two { get; set; }
        public TextView TwoT { get; set; }
        public RadioButton Three { get; set; }
        public TextView ThreeT { get; set; }
        public RadioButton Family { get; set; }
        public TextView FamilyT { get; set; }
        public Spinner spinner { get; set; }
    }
    public List<Food.Pizza> _Pizzalst;
    private Activity _context;

    public PizzaAdapter(Activity context,List<Pizza> plist )
    {
        _context = context;
        _Pizzalst = plist;
    }

    public override Object GetItem(int position)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        MyViewHolder holder = null;
        var view = convertView;
        if (view != null)
            holder = view.Tag as MyViewHolder;
        if (holder == null)
        {
            holder = new MyViewHolder();
            view = _context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.PizzaListItemLayout, null);

            holder.Chb = view.FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.chbpizza);
            holder.Name=view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txt_pizzaname);
            holder.Content = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txt_content);
            holder.OneT=view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txt_one);
            holder.One = view.FindViewById<RadioButton>(Resource.Id.radioButton1);
            holder.One.CheckedChange += Radio_CheckedChange;
            holder.TwoT = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txt_two);               
            holder.Two = view.FindViewById<RadioButton>(Resource.Id.radioButton2);
            holder.Two.CheckedChange += Radio_CheckedChange;
            holder.ThreeT = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txt_three);               
            holder.Three = view.FindViewById<RadioButton>(Resource.Id.radioButton3);
            holder.Three.CheckedChange += Radio_CheckedChange;
            holder.FamilyT = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txt_family);               
            holder.Family = view.FindViewById<RadioButton>(Resource.Id.radioButton4);
            holder.Family.CheckedChange += Radio_CheckedChange;
            holder.spinner = view.FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spinner);
            view.Tag = holder;

        }
        var adapter = ArrayAdapter.CreateFromResource(
               _context, Resource.Array.Numbers, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem);
        adapter.SetDropDownViewResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);
        holder.spinner.Adapter = adapter;
        holder.FamilyT.Text = Convert.ToString(_Pizzalst[position].Family);
        holder.ThreeT.Text = Convert.ToString(_Pizzalst[position].Three);
        holder.TwoT.Text = Convert.ToString(_Pizzalst[position].Two);
        holder.OneT.Text = Convert.ToString(_Pizzalst[position].One);
        holder.Content.Text = _Pizzalst[position].Content;
        holder.Name.Text = _Pizzalst[position].Name;
        return view;
    }

    void Radio_CheckedChange(object sender, CompoundButton.CheckedChangeEventArgs e)
    {
       what to do here??
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get { return _Pizzalst.Count; }
    }
```

and this is my activity:

```
public ListView PizzaListView;
    public Button _SubmitPizza;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.PizzalistLayout);

        PizzaListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.lst_pizza);

        PizzaAdapter myPizzaAdapter=new PizzaAdapter(this,_PizzaLst);
        PizzaListView.Adapter = myPizzaAdapter;

        _SubmitPizza = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btn_submitPizza);
        _SubmitPizza.Click += _SubmitPizza_Click;
    }

    void _SubmitPizza_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        View v;
        string str="";
        for (int i = 0; i < _PizzaLst.Count; i++)
        {
            v = PizzaListView.Adapter.GetView(i, null, null);
            if ((v.FindViewById(Resource.Id.chbpizza) as CheckBox).Checked)
            {
                //do something
            }
        }
```

and the click event for the button is where i want to loop through all of the listview item and see which one has the checkbox that is checked by the user.but there are 2 problems
1-in the listview when i check one of the item some other items become checked too !! i don't know :D

2-in the click event there is no luck and all of the checkboxes are not checked.
what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: you need to create POJO class to make separate catalog of checkbox selected/not selected. & then set it for each list item in GetView method.

Comment: can you explain more?.do i have to set a checkedchange event?i have created the class and have added to the question

Comment: Reference link : http://sunil-android.blogspot.in/2013/04/android-listview-checkbox-example.html